# How to use rc.exe with MSBuild in a .NET project

Tags: .net, msbuild

In a MSBuild project file for a .NET app, I’ve been using rc.exe, and I called it using the `Exec` task, and I retrieved the path to rc.exe from `WindowsSDK80Path`.

This worked fine with Visual Studio 2015, however with VS2017 (without having VS2015 installed), `WindowsSDK80Path` points to a non-existing directory. Unfortunately, I did not find a way to retrieve the new installation path, which on my machine happens to be `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10`.

I don’t know how to use the `RC` task, and I don’t know if it’s the right thing to use, because [the documentation says](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-tasks-specific-to-visual-cpp), “Tasks Specific to Visual C++”.

How can I use rc.exe so that it works with both VS2015 and VS2017 and, if possible, with the next version of Visual Studio as well?

(Note that `GetFrameworkPath` doesn’t retrieve a suitable path.)

Comment: If you build from a VS command prompt, or from within VS, isn't rc.exe in the PATH and you can just call it like that?

Comment: @stijn The VS command prompt would be an option, but that would not work inside VS: within VS, rc.exe is not in the path, at least when MSBuild is called.

Comment: Unless you start VS from the VS command prompt.

Comment: Btw our rc.exe resolution goes something like: try $(WindowsSdkDir)Bin\x86\rc.exe (VS2013 has it like this), else try $(WindowsSdkDir)Bin\$(WindowsTargetPlatformVersion)\x86\rc.exe (e.g. VS2017), else just try rc.exe (in case something is messed up, should be in the PATH then)

Comment: ... where $(WindowsSdkDir) is an environment variable set (eventually) by VsDevCmd.bat, which reads the path from the registry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with this: An `Exec` task calls a PowerShell script, that looks in the registry in `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Windows` for the SDK with the largest version number, retrieves the installation path, and then calls from that path the first `rc.exe` it encounters that is beneath a x86 directory.

A little bit ugly, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

The RC Task is defined in Microsoft.CppCommon.targets which is in C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\v140 on my machine.  You should be able to either just import that targets file in your project or find the  and copy it (with some modifications) to your project.

Edit...

should be a safe way to import that task and allow you to not use a physical path.

Comment: Sounds good, I tried it, but I didn’t manage to. Importing `Microsoft.CppCommon.targets`, MSBuild reports `The target "SetBuildDefaultEnvironmentVariables" does not exist [...]`, which is defined in `Microsoft.Cpp.Current.targets`. Importing that gives a `The imported project "C:\Platform.targets" was not found [...]`. Not sure whether it makes sense to continue in that direction. Moreover, I would need to get the path to `Microsoft.CppCommon.targets`; `VCTargetsPath14` would be an option, but then eventually I’d have to change it to `VCTargetsPath15` or whatever, and I guess that’s by design.